# How to diagnose the failure of "npm start"?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm learning AngularJS. For this purpose, I followed the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and checked out the code of the example (`git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git`).

Then, I ran `npm install` and `npm install -g bower`.

Finally, I tried to launch the web server using `npm start`.

It didn't work and I got following error output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.33
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart angular-phonecat@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info angular-phonecat@0.0.0 Failed to exec prestart script
9 error angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
9 error Exit status 7
10 error Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script.
10 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
10 error not with npm itself.
10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10 error     npm install
10 error You can get their info via:
10 error     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
10 error There is likely additional logging output above.
11 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
12 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
13 error cwd D:\dev\js-learning\angular-phonecat
14 error node -v v0.10.33
15 error npm -v 1.4.28
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
npm install
```

Then:

```
npm start
```

Then open browser and browse to:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Then select /app and you will be brought to:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/#/phones
```

If you are still having issues you could do the following just to get the App running without the testing.

```
npm install express --save
```

Save the following code as server.js to the root:

```
var express  = require('express');  
var http = require('http');
var app = express();        

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app')); 

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express HTTP server listening on port ' + app.get('port')  ) ;
});
```

Then do:

```
node server.js
```

Now browse to:

```
http://localhost:8000
```